# ASP.NET API routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm working on an ASP.NET 5 API and understand that, in order to make the API as "restful" as possible, we use Http verbs as method names.

My question is what happens if I have multiple methods that do different things and all have to be HttpPost?

Say, I have a method that I may call to update a user's first name and may have another method that I use to update the user's city. In both cases, the input parameters will be user ID (GUID) and value which is a string.

```
[HttpPost("id")]
public void Post([FromRoute]id, [FromBody]firstName)
{
   // Change user's first name
}

[HttpPost("id")]
public void Post([FromRoute]id, [FromBody]city)
{
   // Change user's city
}
```

How do I name my methods in this case?

Comment: 2 methods are fine, just use attribute routes to specify different urls. Are they the same URL?

Comment: They can be but they don't have to be. I'm trying to understand the best way to handle it.

Comment: You can use [ActionName(" ")] attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have 2 post methods that do different things, use the "ActionName" attribute.

```
[HttpPost("id")]
[ActionName("FirstNamePost")]
public void FirstNamePost([FromRoute]id, [FromBody]firstName)
{
   // Change user's first name
}

[HttpPost("id")]
[ActionName("CityPost")]
public void CityPost([FromRoute]id, [FromBody]city)
{
   // Change user's city
}
```

So you would call "www.mysite.com/api/citypost/1" or "www.mysite.com/api/FirstNamePost/1"

Another option would be to only have one post method and add a 3rd parameter to distinguish between a name update or city update.

Comment: Side note: for naming you'd be looking for /api/city/name (GET/POST) rather than include "post" in a url...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Agreed!

Answer (score -1):

You can give the controller a route prefix

```
[RoutePrefix("Note")]
public class NoteController
```

then give a specific route to whatever action

```
[Route("", Name = "Note")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get (string tenantName, [FromBody] TagTdo entity)

[Route("", Name = "CreateNote")]
[HttpPost]        
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post (string tenantName, [FromBody] NoteDto entity)

[Route("Update\{id}", Name = "UpdateNote")]
[HttpPut]        
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(string tenantName, [FromBody] NoteDto entity)
```

Then the route will be:

```
\Note [GET]
\Note [POST]
\Note\Update\4 [PUT]
```

Also as a naming convention DON'T use long name in the route, break into several words with slash and http verb

Don't use `GetUserContacts`, use `User\Contacts [GET]`.